# UEFI problem when installing Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: dual-boot, 15.04, uefi, error-handling

When I want to install Ubuntu 15.04 it will show me this information box (see images). When I have Windows installed and want to do a dual boot, I will click Continue in that box, I will install Ubuntu but then I would loose Windows (it happens even if I have partitions set and changed as they should be when dual booting).

I tried to look in BIOS and changed a few settings to Legacy instead of UEFI mode, but no luck :-(

What can I do? Where is the problem? 
I have an ASUS motherboard, AMD 6100 6-core CPU, AMD R7 GPU (if this helps).

Btw, the same thing happens if I want to install Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Gnome...

Thank you for all your answers.

God bless you.

*SCREENSHOT LINK:* 
[image: http://s4.postimg.org/f6q84kgwd/IMG_20150906_144704.jpg]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: Well, the answer is NOT in the 'possible duplicate' topic. :)

Comment: This question is *NOT* a duplicate of the suggested "possible duplicate;" the problem is the *OPPOSITE* of the one covered by that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the computer came with Microsoft Windows pre-installed. Go into you Bios and try installing in CSM boot mode. From what I understand any device pre-installed with Windows is made to have only windows on the UEFI partition, as to preserve the OEM product key Microsoft instills into your UEFI Firmware.

Comment: Well, the thing is that my PC hadn't any OS installed - no Windows, no Linux, no ChromeOS - it came without the OS.

Comment: Did you Purchase your Computer pre-built or build it yourself? Regardless of the circumstances, if you can get into you bios menu. In the Advanced tab...try setting the computer to boot via CSM. It may still help so, try installing Ubuntu on CSM boot mode. If that does not work we shall go from there...FYI, enter Bios by rapidly hitting F2 on startup. Also rapidly hit F12 to enter you Bios based boot options, and boot into your Ubuntu USB show in USB Drive. Or CD/DVD shown in your Disk Drive. if in CSM boot you should be able to install Ubuntu if not I will try to troubleshoot your issue more.

Comment: Hello Tactux, thank you for your suggestion. My PC is pre-built. I will try to reinstall Ubuntu as you said and described. I will let you know about a result! :-)

Comment: Okay, so, enabling CSM and disabling Fastboot option in BIOS fixed my problem. Basically, I used informations from both of the answers. Thank you!

Comment: No problem glad the community could help XD!

Comment: Installing in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode *in this case* is appropriate, since Windows seems to be installed in this mode; but the reasoning of this answer is just plain wrong. In other words, it offers the correct advice for the wrong reasons. Specifically, the EFI System Partition (ESP) is meant to be shared by all OSes on the computer; it is *not* a Microsoft-only location, nor does it have to be left untouched to "preserve the OEM product key." Furthermore, if Windows *were* installed in EFI mode, installing Linux in BIOS mode is a Bad Idea.

Comment: @ Rod Smith With all do respect just because you post a comment with seemingly logical information does not make it correct. In fact there are many wrong statements in your previous comment such as "the EFI System Partition (ESP) is meant to be shared by all OSes on the computer; it is not a Microsoft-only location, nor does it have to be left untouched to "preserve the OEM product key." i'm not saying that its "microsoft only" But the installation process will re-partition some of the computers features so yes "Touching it" will cause you to loose your OEM key

Comment: @ Rod Smith I know for fact as a classmate needed to borrow a laptop and he is not a linux user as i am so i attempted to reinstall my Windows 8.1 OS that was originally on the computer while he used the laptop and i was unable to activate Windows due to partition changes made by installing Linux ie. my OEM key was deleted due to partitioning my HDD so yes you can loose and OEM key by "Touching It"

Comment: @ Rod Smith I may have unintentionally upset you and if so i apologies but the human mind is not a Google search we don't know everything especial because in the Tech world things change and fast too so although there may have been a time where an OEM key was secured through OS changes but sadly we all know Microsoft is to greedy for all that i mean this is the same company that not too long ago fired large amounts of employees by a computer generated software that tell who is "making to much money" long time employees and company life savers were given the hatched due high income

Comment: @ Rod Smith Hey at least Canonical cares about Ubuntu Users, Devs, and Testers we will never see that kinda BS done to make a quick buck.

Comment: Tactux, I'm afraid you're very much mistaken. I have neither the space nor the time to go into it in a series of tiny posts here, but be aware that I'm the author of the GPT fdisk partitioning tool and I maintain the rEFInd boot manager. In other words, I know this subject *very* well. The Windows 8 product key is stored in the EFI's NVRAM, not on the ESP. See [here](http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2015/02/retrieve-microsoft-windows-product-key-from-uefi-shell.html) for details. The [EFI specification](http://www.uefi.org/specifications) covers the ESP in detail.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've got a BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode installation of Windows, but the Ubuntu installer is booting in EFI/UEFI mode. Proceeding with an EFI-mode installation of Ubuntu would likely reach a certain point but then fail. Repairing it at that point would be possible, but only if you know more than you clearly do.

The simplest solution is probably to force your Ubuntu installation medium to boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. This can *usually* be done by using the firmware's built-in boot manager, which is usually accessed by hitting Esc or some function key at boot time. In the boot manager, there are likely to be two entries for your boot medium, one of which includes the string "UEFI" and the other of which doesn't. Select the boot option that *lacks* the "UEFI" string. Alternatively, it may be possible to create an Ubuntu installation USB that lacks the EFI boot loader file, although the details of how to do this vary from one method of writing the USB drive to another.

Stepping back further, IMHO a better way to solve the problem is to re-install everything (both Windows and Ubuntu), but this time in EFI mode. Most modern computers are based on EFI firmware and provide a BIOS compatibility layer (aka a CSM or legacy support) to support older BIOS-mode boot loaders. This feature can usually be disabled in the firmware setup utility, which is desirable because it greatly simplifies the boot process. I describe this issue in more detail on [this page,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) if you're interested in looking into it. Although the emphasis of that page is on the perils of installing Linux in BIOS mode when the computer already has an EFI-mode Windows installation, the principles are the same in your case, just with reversed boot modes for the two OSes. OTOH, disabling the CSM to simplify the boot process means that you'll have to either re-install Windows or jump through hoops to convert it to boot in EFI mode. If you try this and re-install Windows, your best bet is to completely erase the partition table on the disk before you begin the re-installation.

Comment: Hello Rod, thank you very much! Both of your answers had a good impact on the issue and helped solved my issue. 
The sad thing is that I can only check one answer with green icon :( But thank you very much!